# XMLS to CSV using xsltproc

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

When I apply the following xslt

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<output method="text"/>

<template match="/">
  <text>Message: </text><apply-templates/>
</template>
```

on the following xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="text.xsl" type="text"?>
<message>Sample Text.</message>`
```

I get the text "Sample Text" output in Firefox 46.0.1. So the "Message :" is missing.

The output is correct when I use xsltproc.

```
$ xsltproc -o text.csv text.xsl text.xml
$ cat text.csv
Message: Sample Text.
```

Can anybody suggest why the difference?

Comment: The posted stylesheet does not have a closing `</stylesheet>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="styl.xsl" type="text"?>
```

to:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="styl.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```